# How to Shrink/Reset File stderr1 on a SAP System?

Tags: sap

I have a file called **stderr1** in the **work** directory of several of the SAP servers in my production cluster. It has grown to around 19GB's to fill the hard disk on each server.

I have deleted all trace files and WP files from within transaction **SM50** but that hasn't deleted it (or re-named it to .old).

If I try to rename or delete it manually, it says I can't because the file is in use.

Please can you tell me how I can delete or shrink the **stderr1** file?

Comment: SAP version? abap or java? user process explorer or handle from sysinternals to identify the process that holds nadle to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this: I stopped SAP and the SAP Windows services, but was still unable to delete the file. So I rebooted the servers and then was able to delete it.

Since rebooting last night, the file is about 1MB on each server, so we will monitor it.

Also just to note, we do have the cleanup reports running as per OSS notes 48400 and 16083.

I also ran a consistency check and that didn't show any issues

More information here: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?forumID=45&threadID=1702733

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where the file is and :

`echo "" > stderr1`

THat will shrink the file.

Comment: I forgot to say, it is a Windows Server 2003 system :-)

Comment: should still work ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried it and got the message 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'